# Separate YUV420SP to be used in opengl

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk, opengl-es-2.0, yuv

Im currently trying to display a video frame using opengl.
So far it works but I have some color problem.
Im using this as my
[Reference](https://blog.csdn.net/qq_38907791/article/details/93770508) for my logic

I have this code

```
//YUV420SP data
uint8_t *decodedBuff = AMediaCodec_getOutputBuffer(d->codec, status, &bufSize);
buildTexture(decodedBuff, decodedBuff+w*h, decodedBuff+w*h, w, h);
renderFrame();
```

but it displays with wrong color.

decodedBuff = Y

decodedBuff+w*h = U

decodedBuff+w*h*5 = V

but this separation formula is for YUV420P.

Do you guys happen to know whats for YUV420SP?

Your help is very much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it this way you are doing it wrong. You should never manually read raw data from video surfaces in fragment shaders.

Generate a `SurfaceTexture`, bind it to an OpenGL ES texture, and use `EGL_image_external` to access the texture via an external image sampler.

This will give you direct access to the video data in your shader, including automatic handling of the memory format and color conversion, in many cases for "free" because it's backed by GPU hardware acceleration.

Comment: is there a way to achieve that with only native codes ?